# Git dummy needs help on Windows

Tags: git, angular, github

Admittedly, I'm new to Git.  I know... welcome to the century right!  But here's my issue...

I have a repo containing an Angular app.  The app happens to contain an MP4 video file that exceeds the 100mb GitHub limit.  *(Before you recommend that the video shouldn't be local to the app... trust me, it needs to be in this particular case.)*  My initial attempt to push the repo to GitHub failed due to the size of that one file.

**So then I did something stupid...**
I reverted the commit, thinking that it would simply revert back to the state that it was in prior to me attempting to push to GitHub.  But what it ACTUALLY did was restore my repo (entire app) to the original state that it was in when it was created by the Angular CLI... so it was just a new, blank app.

So I deleted the repo, restored my code from a backup, and started over.  This time, I added an exclusion for **.mp4** to my **.gitignore** file.  I was confident that that exclusion would prevent git from trying to push the video up with the commit.  It did not.  So I'm basically in the same boat as yesterday.  I'm in the middle of an unsuccessful push.  The offending video file is in my History and I don't understand why it wasn't excluded, or what I should do to recover.

I am using GitHub Desktop for Windows.  And I have Git version 2.15.0 installed.

I understand that GitHub Desktop may not provide the solution that I need, as it seems to only provide a limited subset of git functionality.  I'm very comfortable working from a command line to do whatever needs to be done.  I'm just not sure what that is.  When attempting to search for solutions to similar scenarios, the responses didn't seem highly relevant, or didn't indicate that they would definitely resolve the issue.

**Here is my .gitignore file**

```
# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db

# Video file exclusion
.mp4
```

Comment: `.mp4` is not the same as `*.mp4`.

Comment: Looks my **.mp4** exclusion probably should have included the * wildcard.  I was thrown off by other entries in the file that appeared to be extensions, but were not preceded by a wildcard.  Rookie mistake I suppose.  Still in need of a safe resolution to my current predicament though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `.mp4` to `*.mp4`, otherwise it will only match files named `.mp4`. You can use `git rm --cached $(file)` to remove files that are already committed without deleting them from the work tree.

Comment: Thanks @SoZettaSho. I did just notice that I was missing the asterisk wildcard.  Using that remove command, will it remove the physical file, or just remove it from my commit?  I'm asking for clarification because the "solutions" that I researched earlier appeared to be MUCH more complex than that.

Comment: `git rm` should remove it from the repo without removing the file (be careful not to accidentally use `rm` without `git`).

Comment: @SoZettaSho - This is incorrect on two fronts.  First, `git rm` will *not* remove a committed file from the repo; it removes from the index (and possibly the work tree, but I'm getting ahead of myself).  Second, by default it *will* delete the version from the work tree; you have to use the `--cached` option to avoid this.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, you are correct.  I went with SoZettaSho's recommendation before I read your response.  I used "-f" to force it, which did actually delete the physical file.  Now that I've replaced it and fixed my .gitignore file though, it is not being pushed up to the repository.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Apologies for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by clearing up a misconception.

`git revert` did *not* delete anything from your repo.  If there was no detailed history lost by deleting the repo and starting over, that's fine; but the revert is not a reason to do that.  What `revert` does is to create one or more patches to "undo" the changes from one or more old commits, and either create a new commit to each patch (the default) or apply all of the patches to the work-in-progress.  Though the post-revert state may have appeared to present an empty work tree, the history was still there (as you would see with `git log`, for example).  This history is the primary reason for using source control, so it's important to understand the difference between an empty work tree and an empty repo.

Immediately after the `revert` command, you could've undone the `revert` with a `reset`, such as

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Even if you did other things in between, you'd be able to safely undo the revert as long as you hadn't successfully pushed anything.  (The exact guideline would be more nuanced, but this is a good starting point for understanding.)  The only trick would be finding a "name" of the original commit to which you want to return.

That said, if you had a backup of the code and the repo had no valuable history, starting with a fresh repo isn't a bad solution to the problem that a large file was already committed to the existing repo.  There are ways to clean up an existing repo and get rid of its large files, but those ways are a bit involved; so in this case a fresh start is reasonable.

But lastly you need to make sure you understand how git's "ignore rule" mechanism works.  Each ignore rule is a pattern that may match one or more paths, and any *untracked* file at such a path is ignored.  A file is "untracked" if there is no entry for that path in the index.  Once a file has been staged (with `git add`) it is in the index, where it typically remains.  (When you `commit`, the file is also added to the database; it's quite hard to remove a file from the database.)

So what you want to do is, as you recreate the repo, before doing any `git add` commands, create your `.gitignore`.  Also make sure it contains a path that matches your file.  As discussed elsewhere `.mp4` will not match "all MP4 files"; that would be `*.mp4`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's helpful.  I assure you though... the revert process (or something related to it) did absolutely squash my code to the out-of-the-box state that it was in before I wrote a single line.  It deleted all of my files and the default files were reverted back to the original state that they were in when the Angular CLI created the directory structure.  So my interpretation of what happened was not just based on what GitHub Desktop was telling me, it was based on what actually happened within my filesystem. I'm in good shape now though.  I truly do appreciate the help!

Comment: "Assure" all you want, but no revert did not squash your code to the out-of-the-box state.  Why would your filesystem be the definitive source of information on this?  The point is that the *repository* still contained all of your work.  You need to understand these issues to use git; if what I'm saying doesn't make sense, you need to start reading up on the tool until it does.  Continuing to use git while believing what you just said would be as good an idea as using a gun without knowing which end the bullets come out.

Comment: Mark, again... thank you for your help.  I really do appreciate it.  And as I said when starting this discussion, I am new to git and I admit that I much to learn.  The conversation seems to descending into insult a little bit though.  I've been in the industry for over 20 years and I'm a life-long developer.  I've also used other source repository systems like TFS for many years, so I'm fairly comfortable with the concept.

Comment: In retrospect... I think I might have realized what caused the reversion of my data (yes... it did definitely happen).  When you create an Angular project using the CLI, it sets up a repo right away and it creates an initial commit (before any code is written).  It seems highly probable that I may have also reverted THAT commit as well.  Can you confirm that THAT action would have reverted my code to a blank slate?

Comment: Incidentally... I'm also a long-time lead firearms instructor on a team of about 10 guys running hundreds of people through training every year. Thankfully, I do know which end the bullets come out. Mark, thanks for your patience with me as I sort through this learning curve!  I'll get up to speed on the important concepts as quickly as I can.  Your time and expertise is certainly appreciated in the meantime.